# API 8 - AsyncTask NullPointerException after 2 rotates

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I start an AsyncTask in the onStart() method, because I want it to always reload the data from the SQLite database when the user returns to that Fragment.  This is because it is a ListFragment, and a click on an item either brings up another Fragment in a two-pane layout on tablets or an Activity that uses ViewPager for all of the items in the list.  In the latter case, I need to reload the items, because the user can delete items from the ViewPager.

Now I am testing my layouts on various devices and APIs.

On a Froyo (API 8) NexusOne AVD, if I rotate the screen once, it starts the AsyncTask again and redisplays the data.  If I do it again, I get a NullPointerException.  This does not occur when I start another AVD using API 10+ (I can rotate the display all I want).  I give it plenty of time to complete the first rotation before doing the second.

Here is the LogCat:

```
11-14 21:03:46.485: E/AndroidRuntime(326): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-14 21:03:46.485: E/AndroidRuntime(326): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-14 21:03:46.485: E/AndroidRuntime(326): at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:271)
11-14 21:03:46.485: E/AndroidRuntime(326): at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:150)
11-14 21:03:46.485: E/AndroidRuntime(326): at com.android.myapp.MyListFragment$MyAdapter.<init>(MyListFragment.java:279)
11-14 21:03:46.485: E/AndroidRuntime(326): at com.android.myapp.MyListFragment$getMyAsync.onPostExecute(MyListFragment.java:393)
11-14 21:03:46.485: E/AndroidRuntime(326): at com.android.myapp.MyListFragment$getMyAsync.onPostExecute(MyListFragment.java:1)
11-14 21:03:46.485: E/AndroidRuntime(326): at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
11-14 21:03:46.485: E/AndroidRuntime(326): at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
11-14 21:03:46.485: E/AndroidRuntime(326): at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
11-14 21:03:46.485: E/AndroidRuntime(326): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-14 21:03:46.485: E/AndroidRuntime(326): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-14 21:03:46.485: E/AndroidRuntime(326): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-14 21:03:46.485: E/AndroidRuntime(326): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-14 21:03:46.485: E/AndroidRuntime(326): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-14 21:03:46.485: E/AndroidRuntime(326): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-14 21:03:46.485: E/AndroidRuntime(326): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-14 21:03:46.485: E/AndroidRuntime(326): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

MyListFragment.java:279 is the call to the **ArrayAdapter**.constructor  [EDIT]

```
super(context, 0, myListArray);
```

onPostExecute(MyListFragment.java:393 is this:

```
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), myListArray);
```

The above does not get executed if myListArray is null.

I added this above that instruction:

```
if (getActivity() == null) {
    Log.d(TAG, "getActivity() is null");
}
```

**getActivity() is returning null on an API 8 device!**

Is this just a bug with the Eclipse/ADT and/or AVD test environment?  Or will it occur on real phones too?

Thanks.

EDIT

Method to start the AsyncTask:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mProgressBarLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    new getListAsync().execute(mType);
}
```

The AsyncTask (inner private class of the ListFragment):

```
    private class getListAsync extends AsyncTask<EFFECT_TYPE, Void, List<Item>> {

    @Override
    protected List<Item> doInBackground(EFFECT_TYPE... params) {
        List<Item> items;
        items = DatabaseManager.get(getActivity()).getItems(params[0]);
        return items;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Item> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mProgressBarLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mItemList = result;
        if (mItemList != null) {
            if (getActivity() == null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "getActivity() is null");  <---- THIS GETS LOGGED ON THE 2nd ROTATE!
            }
393 ----------->    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), mItemList);
            setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
    }

}
```

---

EDIT #2

Well, this is impossible.

I already have onAttach(), so I did this:

Add a new variable to MyListFragment:

```
private Activity mParentActivity = null;
```

Modified onAttach():

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
    mParentActivity = activity;
    if (mParentActivity == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAttach() called with null Activity");
    }
}
```

onPostExecute:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Item> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mProgressBarLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mItemList = result;
        if (mItemList != null) {
            if (mParentActivity  == null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "mParentActivity is null"); 
            }
            mAdapter = new MyAdapter(mParentActivity, mItemList);
            setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
    }

}
```

mParentActivity is NULL there!  Even though onAttach() executed successfully with a valid Activity before it got to the onStart() method.

AsyncTask is broken on API 8.

Comment: Did you find out what variable is null.. in your call to the super..?

Comment: Yea, the context.  See the bottom of my post please.

Comment: You should post more code about how/when trying to use the context.

Comment: It's right there.  I do a getActivity() in the constructor.

Comment: getActivity() may or may not be valid depending on WHERE you call  it. What are you calling getActivity() in? Also a suggestion would be to try this on a device it may be a limitation on the emulator as well.

Comment: I have no idea how to get an API 8 device to try it on. :p

Comment: Post the implementation of MyListFragment's constructor.

Comment: Exactly what I was saying, need more code an context to where this call is happening @Glenn--

Comment: OK.  I added all relevant code.  Thanks.

Comment: Try to stop executing, when you rotate display

Comment: There is nothing running when I do the 2nd rotate.  The first one completes before I do the 2nd one.

Comment: did you try getApplicationContext() instead of getActivity() ?

Comment: You can't do getApplicationContext() in a Fragment.  I would have to do getActivity().getApplicationContext().

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for now.  If anyone knows of a better one, please post it.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mProgressBarLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {
        new getItemsAsync().execute(mType);  // Do the AsyncTask for API 10+
    } else {
        // For FROYO only, do the operation on the main thread
        mItemsList = DatabaseManager.get(mParentActivity).getItems(mType);
        mProgressBarLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (mItemsList != null) {
            mAdapter = new MyAdapter(mParentActivity, mItemsList);
            setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

This works.