# Stange onPause / onResume behaviour

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

I am seeing some strange behaviour with `onPause` / `onResume` in my app and cannot work out what is happening.

I perform a database query (simple subclass of `AsyncTask`) in `onResume` and cancel it in `onPause` if it is still executing. I received a crash report that made me wonder if the task cancel was working or not so added an analytics event to record `onPostExecute` getting called after `onPause` had cancelled the task.

Over the last month I have seen 140 of these events for 4,100 page views.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mIsResumed = true;
    if (mReverseCardsTask == null) {
        mReverseCardsTask = new TcgCursorTask(this) {
            @Override
            protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... params) {
                return mDb.reverseFetchCards();
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Cursor cursor) {
                if (mIsResumed) {
                    onReverseCardsCursor(cursor);
                } else {
                    EasyTracker.getTracker().sendEvent("error", "on-post-execute", "called after paused", 1L);
                }
            }
        };
        mReverseCardsTask.execute();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mIsResumed = false;
    if (mReverseCardsTask != null) {
        mReverseCardsTask.cancel(false);
        mReverseCardsTask = null;
    }
}
```

I have a feeling I am missing something very simple here, but can't see it.

I just noticed I am not clearing `mReverseCardsTask` in `onPostExecute`, but that should not matter.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?  That would help a lot.

Comment: I don't have stack traces. This is happening in my published app. I never saw it happen in person, I can just see the analytics event I put into the code to confirm my suspicion.

Comment: Ahhhh.  I just looked at the `AsyncTask` code from Gingerbread. It has a bug in that it does not check if the task has been cancelled before processing the `MESSAGE_POST_RESULT` message from the background thread. That is _really_ annoying. This means that there is a race condition that makes `cancel()` semantics more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.  I have worked it out.  I am not sure which API version it was fixed in, but if you look at the code for Gingerbread there is a clear race condition in the `cancel()` handling. The GUI thread code which processes the `MESSAGE_POST_RESULT` message from the background calls `onPostExecute()` regardless of whether or not the task was cancelled.

It turns out that the fix is quite simple.  All I need to do is add my own check of `isCancelled()` before executing my `onPostExecute()` logic.

The [Gingerbread code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/gingerbread/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java#L415) receives `MESSAGE_POST_RESULT` and calls `finish()`. Then `finish()` calls `onPostExecute()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just calling cancel() doesn't do anything.  You actually have to put checks in the process to determine if it is to be canceled and do the job of canceling it.

The OS doesn't know what you may need to do to clean things up (like closing files or open network connections) before stopping.

Comment: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java

According to the code above, calling `cancel()` should prevent the `AsyncTask` from calling `onPostExecute()` when it receives the `MESSAGE_POST_RESULT` message from the thread.

Comment: Hmm, it does say that.  But I had the same problem with an AsyncTaskLoader.  The only way to stop it from throwing various kinds of exceptions was to have the onStopLoading() method also set a flag in the SQLiteDatabaseHelper, so I could check it in the various loops I had to add items to the DB.  Without any checks it would never stop the thread, and it would still be running the next time I started it, causing SQLite exceptions.

Comment: It's probably a concurrency problem.  On some devices, the setting of that flag on the UI thread may not happen fast enough for the background thread to see it before calling onPostExecute().  AsyncTask is known to be problematic and buggy.

Comment: I could be misunderstanding how the `Handler` works, but I thought the whole point is that `handleMessage()` method executes on the GUI thread. This means that there can be no race between my `onPause()` code that cancels the task and the code which invokes `onCancelled()` or `onPostExecute()`

Comment: I had another problem with an AsyncTask, I posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994187/api-8-asynctask-nullpointerexception-after-2-rotates

Comment: You started me thinking that it might be an API version specific problem. I replaced my analytics event with

    `try { throw new RuntimeException(): }
    catch (RuntimeException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`

then tried the code on my 4.1.2 phone and my 2.3.3 phone. I could not get it to misbehave on 4.1.2, but after a minute or so of rotating the phone like crazy saw a stack trace in my logs.
Time to read the `AsyncTask` code from 2.3.3...

Comment: I ended up getting rid of it in that situation and putting the data in an Application class, so it would persist across config changes and other activities.  Also, why do it in onPause/Resume?  Many things can pause it, like a notification or pop-up message.